# Get Earliest or Latest Date of Row Detail in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like so. The way it works is that the billing occurs daily to make sure that accounts are current.

```
+------+------------+-------------+
| ID   | AcctType   | BillingDate |
+------+------------+-------------+
| 100  | Individual | 2020-01-01  |
| 100  | Individual | 2020-01-02  |
| 100  | Individual | 2020-01-03  |
| 101  | Group      | 2020-01-01  |
| 101  | Group      | 2020-01-02  |
| 101  | Individual | 2020-01-01  |
+------+------------+-------------+
```

What I need to find is the first and last AcctType of each plan by ID since the AcctType can change. I am using MySQL and the aggregation of `select ID, AcctType, min(BillingDate) from table group by ID` won't work because AcctType will return a random value associated with the ID. How do I reliably get the latest and earliest AcctType by ID? Using version 5.6.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select distinct
    id,
    first_value(acctType) over(
        partition by id 
        order by billingDate 
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    ) firstAccType,
    last_value(acctType) over(
        partition by id 
        order by billingDate 
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    ) lastAccType
from mytable
```

This generates a single record for each `id`, with the first and last value of `accType` in columns.

In earlier versions, using correlated subquery is probably the simplest solution to achieve the same result:

```
select distinct 
    id,
    (
        select t1.accType 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.id = t.id 
        order by billingDate asc
        limit 1
    ) firstAccType,
    (
        select t1.accType 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.id = t.id 
        order by billingDate desc
        limit 1
    ) lastAccType
from mytable
```

Comment: Sorry using older version here. 5.6

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs: I updated my answer with a solution for ealier versions.